# two fonts in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mathpazo

In math mode (e.g. between `$  $`) I would like to use by default computer modern math but to define a new character with a different font e.g. mathpazo. Practically, i want to define a new command `\mycommand{T}` which use mathpazo for T. Is it possible? I saw that a similar question was asked but for matrices, here I just want one new character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

Comment: With fonts, then the particular way you invoke tex can make a big difference.  Are you using Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX?

Comment: @Thorsten Possibly, but if the questioner is using XeTeX or LuaTeX then there's a way to do this using unicode-math which isn't mentioned at that question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's a good point. I wasn't aware of this. (I _never_ use maths in my documents)

Comment: The MathPazo T is very similar to the CM one: the reader will have a hard time in distinguishing one from the other.

Answer (score 16):

Try this. I created a command for `mathpazo` U as well, because it's easier to see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{pazoletters}{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pazoT}{\mathalpha}{pazoletters}{"54}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pazoU}{\mathalpha}{pazoletters}{"55}
\begin{document}
$U \pazoU$ $T \pazoT$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you need more letters, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathpazo{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$Math$ V.S. $\mathpazo{Math}$

\end{document}
```

But if only one or two letters are needed, use `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareMathSymbol` would be better.