# Two different calligraphic font styles in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-operators, calligraphy

I have been succesful in using the `calrsfs` package together with the standard CM type1cm font. I have been able to obtain in separate documents different calligraphic symbols in math mode with `\mathcal{}` for e.g. transform operators: `\mathcal{F}`, `\mathcal{L}`, ...

I am considering two different operators in one single document, with each the letter 'L' in calligraphic style, but in a different font.

I am working with MikTeX 2.8 / 2.9 and CM. I have considered [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode) on this forum, as well as The LaTeX Companion.

The topic [two fonts in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53537/two-fonts-in-math-mode) seems to offer the complete solution. However, where do I find the reference to the desired fonts ? The LaTeX Companion refers to `nfssfont.tex`. I would like to utilize the `fourier` math font.

- Where do I find the reference to the fourier font in the command

  ```
  \DeclareSymbolFont{pazoletters}{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
  ```
- I would like to utilize the `fourier` font to declare the first symbol with *newcommand*, then invoke the `calrsfs` package to have the second symbol in another font in calligraphic mode. Is it necessary to invoke the corresponding packages ?

  ```
  \usepackage{fourier} 
  \newcommand{\L_a}{\mathcal{L}

  \usepackage{calrsfs}    
  \newcommand{\L_b}{\mathcal{L}}
  ```

Once the font is in place with any of the previous method, declaring the new symbols is done with the `\DeclareMathSymbol` command (without declaring a complete new alphabet).

```
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\L_a}{12}{fourier}{"4C}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\L_b}{12}{calrsfs}{"4C}
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You should also consider using the `unicode-math` package together with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. You should highlight your code.

Comment: @canaaerus : I really would like to compile with latex then ps2pdf. I'll have a look at `unicode-math`

Comment: One document I was looking for was the font encoding guide by Mittelbach et alia http://is.gd/vwlD1D

Answer (score 46):

The calligraphic letters are in the OMS encoding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\La}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Lb}{\pazocal{L}}
\begin{document}
$\La\Lb$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To more clearly distinguish most calligraphic letters from the normal ones, you can replace \pazocal by pzccal:
[image]
However, "L" seems fine to me also in \pazocal.

You might also wish to replace calrsfs by dutchcal (visible below), but that is just a matter of taste:
[image]

As shown above, dutchcal contains also bold letters, and both dutchcal and pzccal contain also lowercase letters, unlike the fonts you used.

How to produce these in a TeX file:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641540/122046