# calligraphic forms for math/logic symbols

Tags: fonts, calligraphy

Is there a calligraphic form for   $\exists$ and other logic quantifiers? I tried the approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69085/two-different-calligraphic-font-styles-in-math-mode) but that only gives the usual font for this symbol.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘calligraphic’? Can you point to some source?

Comment: I do not have an exact definition. Something on the artistic/elaborate side and other than the plain inverted E.

Comment: If you load `graphicx` package you could try this: `\newcommand\calexists{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathcal{E}$}}` but (in my opinion) it does not look very nice with the E in the mathcal font.  The A is slightly better.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks for the code. I was afraid that would be the only option! How would your code be changed if one were to flip, as in $x\to -x$, instead of rotate by 180?

Comment: `\newcommand*{\calexists}{\reflectbox{$\exists$}}`

Comment: Or sticking with `\cal`, `\newcommand\calexists{\reflectbox{$\mathcal E$}}`.  But this looks even worse (again in my opinion) because it slants the wrong way.  And the curly E just like an odd 3.

Comment: @egreg I suppose the fonts at the bottom of [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2203/fontsupport.htm) are the closest to calligraphic. Using the fonts listed in The LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List, under a variety  of math font packages, I could not produce anything different from the ordinary $\exists$.

Comment: @Maesumi I've never seen ‘exists’ other than in the ordinary geometric shape.