# How to make $\exists$ bold

Tags: bold, boldmath

I have looked in 
[symbols file](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)
and tried various forms of $\exists$ with various fonts but I always get something that appears very thin. As if there is no bold version. Is there a way of approximating a bold version? I am assuming this applies to many of logic symbols.

I had a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142431/calligraphic-forms-for-math-logic-symbols), which was closed due to lack of clarity.
There the suggestion was to take letter E and rotate or flip it. The results are not that satisfactory.

Comment: $\boldsymbol{\exists}$ ?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{bm}\begin{document}$\exists\bm{\exists}$\end{document}`. However, in most fonts, the thin `\exists` is what you want; the font designers know why they make it thin: it shall be thin, thicker would be really ugly.

Comment: @Zarko     Now I see that if I put on good glasses and compare them side-by-side, as in yo' code, I notice a difference. But decidedly the bold is still thin!

Comment: `\reflectbox{E}` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... several ideas (to be surrounded by `\mathop`, or `\mathord` — really do not know). You can change easily the thickness and proportion of the `tikz` symbol changing the `line width`, `x` and `y` keys, and align it with the `baseline` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Exists}{\bm{\exists}\kern-0.6em\bm{\exists}}
\newcommand{\ReallyExists}{\tikz[baseline=-0.7pt,line width=1.4pt,
    line cap=round, x=0.5em,y=0.3em] 
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) (1,1) -- (1,2) -- (0,2);} 
\begin{document}
Test: $\exists\,\bm{\exists}\,\Exists\,\ReallyExists$
\end{document}
```

[image: it really exists...]