# Three different calligraphic font styles in mathmode with musixtex

Tags: fonts, math-operators, calligraphy

This question could be a continuation of the answer given by @egreg in this link
[Two different calligraphic font styles in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69085/two-different-calligraphic-font-styles-in-math-mode).

In my book I use both `\mathcal{}` and `\pazocal{}` commands for the calligraphic math symbols. This afternoon I have seen that [musixtex](/questions/tagged/musixtex) package has also of the calligraphic font the **P**.

Is it possible to declare in math-mode a third calligraphic math symbol using the macro of [musixtex](/questions/tagged/musixtex) named `\DEP` like this image (pag. 92 of the manual):

[image]

I just need only for the **P** and the other letters if they exist (but I doubt that they will exist), how must I to do without disturbing the commands `\mathcal` and `\pazocal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is `musix24` and the character's slot is 34.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% the font is musix24, but it has to be scaled
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{musix}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{musix}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.7] musix24}{}
% the character has zero width, so we need an explicit space
\DeclareRobustCommand{\anotherP}{%
  \mspace{2mu}% a small sidebearing
  \text{\usefont{U}{musix}{m}{n}\symbol{34}\hspace{1em}}%
  \mspace{2mu}% a small sidebearing
}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{P}\ne\anotherP$

% show the bounding box
\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\anotherP$}\fbox{$\mathcal{P}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Approved with a lot of happiness....:-) "Grazie infinite".