# Creating arrow plot with tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, overleaf

How can I make with tikz in latex, something like in the following plot?
[image]

Do you have any reccomendation where to search anything like this in overleaf or maybe if someone could tell me what commands to work with?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What do you have so far? Where is the problem? You could just use nodes, relative positioning, and draw arrows with nodes between. If you don't know where to start, you can have a look at some examples on [texample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/) and start from there.

Comment: @Nav89: here is a suggestion for you `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) node (i) {$i$}  
(0,1.5) node (G) {$G$}
;
\draw[->] (i) to node[right]{$F^i$} (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you

Comment: @BlackMild thank you very much!

Comment: @Nav89 Do you mean that you can follow my code to finish the figure?

Comment: @BlackMild actually no! It bever worked....and i have no idea how all this work right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution for your first question on texSE. The package [calrsfs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69109/140722) is needed to get the symbols `C` and `I`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\path 
(0,0) node (i) {$i$}         
(0,1.5) node (G) {$G$} 
(2.5,0) node (C) {$\mathcal{C}$} 
(-2.5,0) node (I) {$\mathcal{I}$} 
; 
\begin{scope}[>=stealth,nodes={scale=.6,magenta}]
\draw[->] (i) to node[right]{$F^i\left(x^i_{\mathcal{I}},y^i\right)$} (G); 
\draw[->] (i) to node[above]{$t^i$} (C); 
\draw[<-] (i) to node[above]{$x^i_{\mathcal{I}}$} (I); 
\draw[->] (C)--++(0,-1)-|(i) node[above,pos=.25]{$y^i$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]
  & A\\
  B\ar[r,"x"] & C\ar[r,"y"]\ar[u,"z"']\ar[d, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z}]
  & D\ar[l,"w"{pos=0.75},to path={
      -- (\tikztostart.south)
      |- (Z) \tikztonodes
      -| (\tikztotarget.south)
      -- (\tikztotarget)
  }]\\
  & {}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely you use a MAC...it is very nice the resolution of your image.

Comment: A really good guess just by seeing an image. I’m afraid what else you can know :)