# Multiple math fonts in classicalthesis

Tags: fonts, fontspec, classicthesis

I've already written more than the half of certain text using classicthesis.sty.
I love the font I'm working with (whatever its name: Palatino?) but I just realized that I have to use `$\Upsilon$` and, it is displayed as a letter rather closer to a ordinary `$Y$`--which is not incorrect, but I don't like. I want to change this `$\Upsilon$` to other font, say, the ordinary one.

A solution I found is using,

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{pazoletters}{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Ups}{\mathalpha}{pazoletters}{"7}
```

as suggested in "[two fonts in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53537/two-fonts-in-math-mode)", but the capital upsilon is still not the font I want. How can I change the pazzoletters into the usual font?

I guess there is a way to call another font, without having to install lot of .sty-files, as required by some nice anwers (I don't think I need to use powerful packages) How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\Upsilon` symbol in `mathpazo` is exactly the same as an Y. You can borrow the one in the Computer Modern family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Ups}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{"7}

\begin{document}
$\Upsilon\Ups$
\end{document}
```

[image]